# SQL Server : Trigger Update Using One Query

Tags: sql-server

I have a trigger that logs to an `Audit` table when certain columns are updated. I am having so much problem with using `columns_updated()` after deleting a column, so I am rewriting the trigger just use `Update()` only, which seems to work.

However, I keep repeating the query in every `IF` statement, `If Update(ColumnName)`, see below code, because I need to change the column name dynamically. Is there a way to trick this, so I don't have to keep repeating the `INSERT` query?

```
IF (@TYPE IN ('U') and UPDATE(ShippingAddressFlag))
    BEGIN   
        SELECT @fieldname = 'ShippingAddressFlag'
        SELECT @SQL =       'insert Audit (Type, TableName, PKCol, PK, FieldName, OldValue, NewValue, UpdateDate, DBUserName, UserID)'
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ' select ''' + @TYPE + ''''
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ',''' + @TableName + ''''
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ',''' + @PKCol + ''''
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ',' + @PK
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ',''' + @fieldname + ''''
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ',convert(varchar(1000),d.' + replace(@fieldname, '''', '') + ')'
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ',convert(varchar(1000),i.' + replace(@fieldname, '''', '') + ')'
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ',''' + @UpdateDate + ''''
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ',''' + @UserName + ''''
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ',''' + @UserID + ''''
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ' from #ins i full outer join #del d'
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    @PKCols
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ' where i.' + @fieldname + ' <> d.' + @fieldname 
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is null and  d.' + @fieldname + ' is not null)' 
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is not null and  d.' + @fieldname + ' is null)'
        Print @SQL
    END

IF (@TYPE IN ('U') and UPDATE(Amount))
    BEGIN
        SELECT @fieldname = 'Amount'
        SELECT @SQL =       'insert Audit (Type, TableName, PKCol, PK, FieldName, OldValue, NewValue, UpdateDate, DBUserName, UserID)'
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ' select ''' + @TYPE + ''''
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ',''' + @TableName + ''''
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ',''' + @PKCol + ''''
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ',' + @PK
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ',''' + @fieldname + ''''
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ',convert(varchar(1000),d.' + replace(@fieldname, '''', '') + ')'
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ',convert(varchar(1000),i.' + replace(@fieldname, '''', '') + ')'
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ',''' + @UpdateDate + ''''
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ',''' + @UserName + ''''
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ',''' + @UserID + ''''
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ' from #ins i full outer join #del d'
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    @PKCols
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ' where i.' + @fieldname + ' <> d.' + @fieldname 
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is null and  d.' + @fieldname + ' is not null)' 
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL +    ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is not null and  d.' + @fieldname + ' is null)'
        Print @SQL
    END
```

Comment: **HOLY CRAP!** - this is a monster of a trigger. I would strongly recommend to rethink this - a **trigger** can fire at any time, many times, and you have no control over when and how many times it gets executed. A trigger therefore should be **nimble** and **lean** - just a few lines of code **at most** - but it shouldn't be such a monster! This will be **killing your performance** for sure!

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. any method to not repeat the query for updating multiple columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the performance of the following but you can use `unpivot` to get a similar effect

Given any `audit` table as

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.AuditLog
(
    DatabaseName        SYSNAME,
    SchemaName          SYSNAME,
    TableName           SYSNAME,
    ColumnName          SYSNAME,
    KeyValue            SQL_VARIANT,
    OldValue            SQL_VARIANT,
    NewValue            SQL_VARIANT,
    TransactionType     VARCHAR(10),
    LogDate             AS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
GO
```

then an 'ordinary' table you want to log

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Col1 INT,
    Col2 INT,
    Col3 INT
)
GO
```

a trigger for logging changes using `unpivot` would be

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.trg_MyTable_AuditLog
ON dbo.MyTable
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
NOT FOR REPLICATION
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DATABASENAME   SYSNAME = DB_NAME(),
            @TABLENAME      SYSNAME = N'MyTable',
            @SCHEMANAME     SYSNAME = N'dbo',
            @INSERTED       SMALLINT = 1,
            @DELETED        SMALLINT = 2,
            @UPDATED        SMALLINT = 3

    DECLARE @action SMALLINT = 0

    SELECT @action = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted) THEN @INSERTED ELSE 0 END + 
                        CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM deleted) THEN @DELETED ELSE 0 END 

    IF @action = @INSERTED
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.AuditLog (DatabaseName, SchemaName, TableName, ColumnName, KeyValue, OldValue, NewValue, TransactionType)
        SELECT @DATABASENAME, @SCHEMANAME, @TABLENAME, ColumnName, Id, NULL, NewValue, 'INSERT'
        FROM inserted
        UNPIVOT (
            NewValue
            FOR ColumnName IN ( Col1, Col2 )
        ) upiv
    END

    IF @action = @DELETED
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.AuditLog (DatabaseName, SchemaName, TableName, ColumnName, KeyValue, OldValue, NewValue, TransactionType)
        SELECT @DATABASENAME, @SCHEMANAME, @TABLENAME, ColumnName, Id, OldValue, Null, 'DELETE'
        FROM deleted
        UNPIVOT (
            OldValue
            FOR ColumnName IN ( Col1, Col2 )
        ) upiv
    END

    IF @action = @UPDATED
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.AuditLog (DatabaseName, SchemaName, TableName, ColumnName, KeyValue, OldValue, NewValue, TransactionType)
        SELECT @DATABASENAME, @SCHEMANAME, @TABLENAME, upiv_inserted.ColumnName, 
                upiv_inserted.Id, upiv_deleted.OldValue, upiv_inserted.NewValue, 'UPDATE'
        FROM (
            SELECT ColumnName, Id, NewValue
            FROM inserted
            UNPIVOT (
                NewValue
                FOR ColumnName IN ( Col1, Col2 )
            ) upiv
        ) upiv_inserted
        JOIN (
            SELECT  ColumnName, Id, OldValue
            FROM deleted
            UNPIVOT (
                OldValue
                FOR ColumnName IN ( Col1, Col2 )
            ) upiv
        ) upiv_deleted
        ON upiv_deleted.Id = upiv_inserted.Id
        AND upiv_deleted.ColumnName = upiv_inserted.ColumnName
        WHERE upiv_deleted.OldValue <> upiv_inserted.NewValue
    END
END
GO
```

To do this the columns being unpivoted have to be the same data type so  you may need to add some derived tables casting columns as appropriate.

Also it would seem that `unpivot` is sensitive to the length of `varchar`s and collations, a nicer solution then unpivoting derived tables would be to use `cross apply` instead of `unpivot`. `cross apply` does not seem to have the same 'sensitivity' to string lengths and can have expressions applied to the column more succinctly.

This would mean changing the previous pivots to

```
INSERT INTO dbo.AuditLog (DatabaseName, SchemaName, TableName, ColumnName, KeyValue, OldValue, NewValue, TransactionType)
SELECT @DATABASENAME, @SCHEMANAME, @TABLENAME, ColumnName, Id, OldValue, Null, 'DELETE'
FROM deleted
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES
        ('Col1', Col1),
        ('Col2', Col2)
) upiv (ColumnName, OldValue)
```

Edit for comment:

```
IF @action = @UPDATED
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.AuditLog (DatabaseName, SchemaName, TableName, ColumnName, KeyValue, OldValue, NewValue, TransactionType)
    SELECT @DATABASENAME, @SCHEMANAME, @TABLENAME, upiv_inserted.ColumnName, 
            upiv_inserted.Id, upiv_deleted.OldValue, upiv_inserted.NewValue, 'UPDATE'
    FROM (
        SELECT ColumnName, Id, NewValue
        FROM inserted
        CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES
            ('Col1', Col1),
            ('Col2', Col2)
        ) upiv (ColumnName, NewValue)
    ) upiv_inserted
    JOIN (
        SELECT  ColumnName, Id, OldValue
        FROM deleted
        CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES
            ('Col1', Col1),
            ('Col2', Col2)
        ) upiv (ColumnName, OldValue)
    ) upiv_deleted
    ON upiv_deleted.Id = upiv_inserted.Id
    AND upiv_deleted.ColumnName = upiv_inserted.ColumnName
    WHERE upiv_deleted.OldValue <> upiv_inserted.NewValue
END
```

Comment: I am having a problem like you mentioned "data type".  Basically, I just change Col1 to FirstName (varchar), and Col2 to LastName (varchar) and it failed. any suggestion?

Comment: @milacay: I believe the suggestion was right there after mentioning the issue: `you may need to add some derived tables to cast some columns`. I.e. don't select `FROM inserted` but instead select `FROM (SELECT ... CAST(Col1 AS ...), CAST(Col2 AS ...), ... FROM inserted)` or something like that before unpivoting.

Comment: @T I, can you show me the "CROSS APPLY" for @Updated section? thanks